# Google map v2: how to set Current user location latitude and longitude not by default

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to set the current user location latitude and longitude.By default it have to take the latitude and longitude where ever I move.

```
  double startLatitude;
  double startLongitude;
  LatLng start;

  startLatitude =currentLocation.getLatitude();
  startLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();

  start = new LatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude);

 new Routing(getParent(), mMap, txtDistance).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, start, end);
```

I had done a code like that so far.But it wasn't worked for me.I dont know how to set the langitude and longitude not by default.

it have to take the current user location latitude and longitude wherever I move.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Fused Location Provider as instructed [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Have this permission specified in your manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

In your activity's `onCreate()` method, create an instance of Google API Client using `GoogleApiClient.Builder`. Use the builder to add the `LocationServices API`.

`protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}`

Follow this guide to see how set up Google Client API. 
[Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#Starting)

Once you have connected to Google Play services and the location services API, you can get the last known location of a user's device.

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Who ever down voted please have the decency to point out what's wrong with this answer. If this is not how Google recommends to get the current location of the user now then what is?